# Javascript not executing after ajax partial rendering in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I cannot figure out how to get the html/javascript loading correctly. Thus highcharts doesnt have the correct div loaded to render the chart when it is run.

I have a menu partial:

```
<ul class='kwicks kwicks-vertical'>
    <li id='panel-1'><%= link_to_unless_current image_tag('keyIssues.png'), load_key_issues_path, remote: true %></li>
    <li id='panel-2'><%= link_to_unless_current image_tag('pollVsLeader.png'), load_polls_path, remote: true  %></li>
</ul>
```

That when called runs a method home_controller.rb:

```
def load_key_issues
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html { render :action => "refresh", :notice => 'Update SUCCESSFUL!' }
    end
end
```

That then runs load_key_issues.js.erb:

```
$("#replace").html("<%= j render partial: 'shared/key_issues' %>");
```

Which then renders this html in a partial:

```
<div class="col span_6_of_7">
    <section id="infographic">
        <div id ="infographicContent">
            <%= javascript_include_tag "highcharts" %>
            <%= javascript_include_tag "chart" %>
            <div id="chart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 700px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>
    </section>  
</div>
```

I don't know how to get this sequence correct, can anyone be of assistance please?

Comment: `jQuery.html()` will strip out script tags. Can use `jQuery.load()` to load div with ajax...it preserves and allows script execution. Otherwise why do you need to use javacript to set the html ? See jQuery API docs

Comment: what is your browser console saying? when you inspect AJAX response, is it correctly formatted?

Comment: Do you receive any errors, how your request looks like after ajax calling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include your javascript in the main page into which you are loading the partial.

Comment: my javascript has a lot of logic that has to do with the object that is being rendered. Is there another way to fix this problem?

Comment: not dry at all, especially for form code, like ckeditor. putting the script tag in the form partial would be nice.